# Students Records in Python

Tags: python-3.x

Am working on a program but it does not run well. It takes all the records but does not display all of them it just displays the last record entered. 
On the program there is choosing options and the second(Displays Performance List) and third(Display Transcripts) option are not working correctly...here is the program

```
# List is stored
list1 = []

# Program prompts you to login
username = input("Enter a Username\n")
password = "password"
password = input("Enter Password\n")
if (password == "password"):
    print("Password Accepted")
    print("Welcome - Access Granted")
else:
     print("Password Denied")
while(password == "password"):

    # Program displays a menu
    print("GRAFFINS COLLEGE")
    print("CAPS DEPARTMENT")
    print("[1] Record Marks")
    print("[2] Displays Performance List")
    print("[3] Display Transcripts")
    print("[4] Exit")
    print("Please Enter an Option")

    # Input an option from the menu
    option = int(input("Option: "))

    # For option 1
    if option == 1:

        # Prompt to enter the number of students
        # Input number of students
        print("Enter the number of students to record")
        no_of_students = int(input("Number of students: "))

        # Initialize count
        count = 0

        # Loop to repeat while count is less than the number entered
        while count < no_of_students:

            # Prompt to enter Student's Admission Number
            # Input Admission Number
            print("\nEnter student's admission number")
            adm_number = input("Adm. Number: ")

            # Prompt to enter Student's Name
            # Input Student's name
            print("\nEnter student's name")
            std_name = input("Student's Name: ")

            # Prompt to enter windows marks
            # Input windows marks
            print("\nEnter Performance in Windows")
            windows = int(input("Windows: "))

            # Prompt to enter word marks
            # Input word marks
            print("\nEnter Performance in Word")
            word = int(input("Word: "))

            # Prompt to enter excel marks
            # Input excel marks
            print("\nEnter Performance in Excel")
            excel = int(input("Excel: "))

            # Prompt to enter access marks
            # Input access marks
            print("\nEnter Performance in Access")
            access = int(input("Access: "))

            # Prompt to enter powerpoint marks
            # Input powerpoint marks
            print("\nEnter Performance in Powerpoint")
            powerpoint = int(input("Powerpoint: "))

            # Prompt to enter internet marks
            # Input internet marks
            print("\nEnter Performance in Internet")
            internet = int(input("Internet: "))

            # The list is defined
            list1 = [adm_number, std_name, windows, word, excel, access, powerpoint, internet]

            # Count increment
            count = count + 1

    # For option 2
    elif option == 2:

        # Command to display the list
        print(list1)

        # Calculation of the total marks
        total = windows + word + excel + access + powerpoint + internet

        # Prompt to display the total marks
        print("Total marks: ")
        print(total)

        # Calculation of mean marks
        mean = total / 6

        # Prompt to display mean
        print("Mean marks: ")
        print(mean)

        # Condition to check whether students has passed or failed
        if mean > 60:
            comment = "pass"
        else:
            comment = "fail"

        # The comment display prompt
        print("Mean grade: ")
        print(comment)

    # For option 3
    elif option == 3:

        # Prompt to enter Student's Admission Number
        # Admission Number input
        print("Enter admission number of student: ")
        adm_number = input("Adm Number: ")

        # Condition to search for the admission number
        for adm_number in list1:
            # List is displayed
            print("Adm_number\tName\twindows\tword\texcel\taccess\tpowerpoint\tinternet")
            print(list1)

    # For option 4
    elif option == 4:

        # Program terminates
        break
```

Comment: It is because `list1`  overwrites after noting each student that's why

Answer (score 0):

You are referring list1 as globally,

- option 1: you referring the list in each loop, instead you have to do

  ```
   list1.append([adm_number, std_name, windows, word, excel, access, powerpoint, internet])
  ```
- option 3: for display the results you have to use

  ```
   
    for adm_number in list1:
       # List is displayed
       print("Adm_number\tName\twindows\tword\texcel\taccess\tpowerpoint\tinternet")
       print('\t'.join(adm_number))
  ```

Or you can use dictionary for storing data like.
`list1 = {}`

For insertion option you have to use as:

```
      list1[adm_number] = [adm_number, std_name, windows, word, excel, access, powerpoint, internet]
```

For display option you have to use as:

```
print("Enter admission number of student: ")
 adm_number = input("Adm Number: ")

 # Condition to search for the admission number
 if adm_number in list1:
    print("Adm_number\tName\twindows\tword\texcel\taccess\tpowerpoint\tinternet")
    print('\t'.join(list1[adm_number]))
```

Comment: am not getting the difference between For display option you have to use as:......and the above

Comment: `print('\t'.join(list1[adm_number])) `, the difference in this based on the input of adm_number, it searches your dictionary and return the list of particular adm_number details

Comment: print('\t'.join(str(v) for v in list1[adm_number])) it worked now